# using itextsharp to read pdf file page size differs with original size

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using iText for .NET to read pdf file page size (both width and height), when I search in the PDF viewer for the document properties, it shows the dimensions in inch:

[image]

I manually convert inch to px it get the dimensions in pixels, but in iText, the `GetPagesize()` method return another value.

What is the reason why the dimension values differ? Which value is correct?

Comment: I've updated your question because (1.) it's iText for .NET, not iTextSharp. We renamed the library 2 years ago (you are probably using an old version). (2.) I replaced the link to the image with the actual image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the assumption that iText gives you the dimension in pixels (`px`) and that assumption is wrong. Please read the FAQ: [How do the measurement systems in HTML relate to the measurement system in PDF?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/how-do-measurement-systems-html-relate-measurement-system-pdf)

> 1 in. = 25.4 mm = 72 user units (PDF)
>
> 1 in. = 25.4 mm = 72 pt (typography)
>
> 1 in. = 25.4 mm = 96 px (images)

You are probably confusing 96 px with 72 pt.

If you divide the values returned by `GetPagesize()` by 72, and you *still* get different dimensions, then there's probably a `/CropBox`. The `GetPageSize()` returns the `/MediaBox` value. However, there's also a `GetCropBox()` method. If no `/CropBox` is defined, then this method will return `null`, and the visible page size will be identical to the actual page size (the `/CropBox` value is assumed to be identical to the `/MediaBox` value).

If the `GetCropBox()` method doesn't returns `null`, then the visible part of the page is *cropped* to a size that is *smaller* than the dimensions defined by the `/MediaBox`. That could explain why the value shown in the PDF viewer is smaller than what you'd expect based on what is returned by the `GetPageSize()` method. You need to use the value returned by the `GetCropBox()` method in this case.

Comment: is there anyway to get inch value?

Comment: How about dividing the values expressed in user units by 72?

Comment: :) currently im using that for my process.any way thank u

Comment: Please clarify: you divide the values returned by `GetPagesize()` by 72, and you get a different result than shown in the document properties in the viewer? That's also possible, but that has a different reason than confusing `pt` and `px`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: after u post  1 in=72 user unit only, i tried that .i got  my ans from ur reply.before i dont know the conversion.ur ans worked for me

Comment: OK, I misunderstood. Since you didn't accept my answer, I thought the problem wasn't solved yet. Please accept answers that solved the problem by clicking the check mark next to the score (which is currently 0, so it looks as if my answer was bad).